# How can I randomly walk between nodes by weights in Neo4j with Python?

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I've created nodes in Neo4j with the following code,

```py
from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship

g = Graph(password='neo4j')
tx = g.begin()

node1 = Node('Node', name='Node-1')
node2 = Node('Node', name='Node-2')
node3 = Node('Node', name='Node-3')
node4 = Node('Node', name='Node-4')
node5 = Node('Node', name='Node-5')
node6 = Node('Node', name='Node-6')
node7 = Node('Node', name='Node-7')

tx.create(node1)
tx.create(node2)
tx.create(node3)
tx.create(node4)
tx.create(node5)
tx.create(node6)
tx.create(node7)

rel12 = Relationship(node1, '0.2', node2, weight=0.2)
rel13 = Relationship(node1, '0.2', node3, weight=0.2)
rel14 = Relationship(node1, '0.6', node4, weight=0.6)
rel45 = Relationship(node4, '0.5', node5, weight=0.5)
rel46 = Relationship(node4, '0.3', node6, weight=0.3)
rel47 = Relationship(node4, '0.2', node7, weight=0.2)

tx.create(rel12)
tx.create(rel13)
tx.create(rel14)
tx.create(rel45)
tx.create(rel46)
tx.create(rel47)

tx.commit()
```

Here is the graph in `Neo4j` interface,
[image: neo4j-graph]

I want to select a node by name and then, I want to walk to another node randomly. But random selection should be like that,

```py
import random

random.choices(['Node-2', 'Node-3', 'Node-4'], weights=(0.2, 0.2, 0.6))
```

I can select the node with following code, but I don't know how to walk to the other node randomly.

```py
from py2neo import Graph
from py2neo.matching import NodeMatcher

g = Graph(password='neo4j')
nodes = NodeMatcher(g)
node1 = nodes.match('Node', name='Node-1').first()
```

If node-1 is the starting point, ways that can be walked,

```
Node-1 -> Node-2
Node-1 -> Node-3
Node-1 -> Node-4 -> Node-5
Node-1 -> Node-4 -> Node-6
Node-1 -> Node-4 -> Node-7
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to be able to only jump to neihhbours? There is random walk procedure available in the neo4j graph data science librarY

Comment: Yes, I just want to jump to neighbours but I have two main conditions. First one is, can I use weights in random walk procedure? And the second one, how can I do this in Python?

Comment: Unfortunately, the algorithm does not support relationship weights. Check the docs for more information: https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/alpha-algorithms/random-walk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Py2neo supports making Cypher queries, and [here is a nice hello-world tutorial](https://nicolewhite.github.io/neo4j-jupyter/hello-world.html) on how to do that.

So, I will provide a commented Cypher query that will hopefully work for you.

But first, a few notes:

- You ***should not*** give relationships that serve the same purpose a virtually infinite number of types (like "0.2", "0.5", etc.), as that is VERY unhelpful when you want to search for specific relationships by type (which is one of the most common things you will want to do) and will cause an enormous number of relationship types. So I assume in my answer that the relationships of interest all actually have the `TO` type.
- My query uses a temporary `Temp` node to store the temporary state of the query as it iterates through the relationships in a random path. The `Temp` node will be deleted at the end of the query.

The query is as follows:

```
// Get the (assumed-unique) starting Node `n` 
MATCH (n:Node)
WHERE n.name = 'Node-1'

// Create (if necessary) the unique `Temp` node, and initialize
// it with the native ID of the starting node and an empty `pathRels` list
MERGE (temp:Temp)
SET temp = {id: ID(n), pathRels: []}
WITH temp

// apoc.periodic.commit() repeatedly executes the query passed to it
// until it returns 0 or NULL.
// The query passed here iteratively extends the list of relationships
// in `temp.pathRels`. In each iteration, if the current `temp.id`
// node has any outgoing `TO` relationships, the query:
// - appends to `temp.pathRels` a randomly-selected relationship, taking
//   into account the relationship weights (which MUST sum to 1.0),
// - sets `temp.id` to the ID of the end node of that selected relationship,
// - and returns 1.
// But if the current `temp.id` node has no outgoing `TO` relationships, then
// the query returns 0.
CALL apoc.periodic.commit(
  "
    MATCH (a:Node)
    WHERE ID(a) = $temp.id
    WITH a, [(a)-[rel:TO]->() | rel] AS rels
    LIMIT 1 // apoc.periodic.commit requires a LIMIT clause. `LIMIT 1` should be harmless here.
    CALL apoc.do.when(
      SIZE(rels) > 0,
      '
       WITH temp, a, REDUCE(s={x: rand()}, r IN rels | CASE
         WHEN s.x IS NULL THEN s
         WHEN s.x < r.weight THEN {x: NULL, pathRel: r}
         ELSE {x: s.x - r.weight} END
       ).pathRel AS pathRel
       SET temp.id = ID(ENDNODE(pathRel)), temp.pathRels = temp.pathRels + pathRel
       RETURN 1 AS result
      ',
      '
       RETURN 0 AS result
      ',
      {temp: $temp, a: a, rels: rels}
    ) YIELD value
    RETURN value.result
  ",
  {temp: temp}
) YIELD batchErrors

// Use the `temp.pathRels` list to generate the `weightedRandomPath`
// (or you could just return `pathRels` as-is).
// Then delete the `Temp` node, since it is no longer needed.
// Finally, return `weightedRandomPath`, and also the `batchErrors` returned by
// apoc.periodic.commit() (in case it had any errors). 
WITH temp, apoc.path.create(STARTNODE(temp.pathRels[0]), temp.pathRels) AS weightedRandomPath, batchErrors
DELETE temp
RETURN weightedRandomPath, batchErrors
```

Comment: It always returns an empty list. Do you have any idea about that? @cybersam

Comment: I found some issues in my code, and also in APOC. WIll update my answer soon.

Comment: Hello again, are there any updates in here @cybersam?